# Deleting hundreds of thousands of lines in a CSV file

Tags: unix

I'm not very experienced with Unix commands, but I'm looking to delete from the second line to the 809,600th line. I tried this:

```
sed '2,809600d' extract.csv
```

..but it didn't seem to have deleted any lines when I do a count. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you are using the `sed` command, what does it have to do with `bash`?

Comment: You should know that `sed` is a filter, i.e., it processes an input and produces an output... it does not change the input file unless you use the `-i`   option. Read the `sed` man pages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You command is right, you just need to edit the file in place using the `-i` option of `sed` otherwise `sed` will show the output on STDOUT rather than actually modifying the file.

Do:

```
sed -i '2,809600 d' extract.csv
```

Or if you want to backup the original file:

```
sed -i.bak '2,809600 d' extract.csv
```

The original file will be backed up as `extract.csv.bak`.

Comment: Or, `sed -i "" '2,809600 d' extract.csv` on BSD/OSX.